# This app is not allowed to query for scheme tel

Tags: objective-c, ios9, xcode7

I just opened an old project onbjectif-c created in 2010, the application works correctly except an interface
is not working.The error is -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "tel: 0" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme tel".

according to my research I find that the error is related to ios 9 but I do not find how to resolve it
thank you

Comment: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://+123456789"]];`

Comment: its for call. if you want other thing then tell

Comment: thank you, please I need a little clarification

Comment: yes, what type of clarification you want ?

Comment: i cant resolve the problem espacially because there are no errors in the source code

Comment: from above code, you can't call ?

Answer (score 44):

I've got the same mistake! The thing is that using phone calls with URL schemes doesn't require a special key in Info.plist. 
The answer is- **in simulator, this will not work, you need to test in device. The simulator doesn't have carrier service.**

Answer (score 36):

This means you have to add the scheme 'tel' in your info.plist, i.e

```
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
            <array>
                    <string>tel</string>
            </array>
```

This will whitelist the scheme 'tel'

Comment: Excellent. In my case I needed to add the entry for <string>https</string>. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

for me this error was shown on the simulator, in testing on a real device it wasn't shown